# Java Client Server File Synchronization - Simplest way

Tags: java

I am trying to add a cloud feature to my java app. I need to synchronize the files in a client and server. I am newbie in java programming and I would like to hear the best option that is availalbe in this case.

I have tried some sample projects like

http://jfilesync.sourceforge.net/

http://sourceforge.net/p/lazysync

https://github.com/quaa/JavaFileSync

But I am really confused in the server part. Actually there will be many user accounts, so I hope I need to create different folders to store data of different users. So what is the best way to achieve this ?
Creating an ftp connection ?
or http upload?

I am not sure. Anyone please guide me to the right path.

Comment: What confuses you? HTTP vs FTP vs plain sockets isn't really important, just pick one. (Though I'd advise against FTP, it makes it harder to deal with firewalls and network tunnels)

Comment: @Joni, thanks for your comment. I loved the concept of DropBox. So is it possible to achieve DropBox like functionality via HTTP ? or which is better ?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really common in Web applications.  Since I don't have a lot of specifics to work from, I'll give you things to think about and general suggestions.

If you 'roll your own' the thing you don't want to do is to store the bytes you upload into the database.  It's possible to do but doing it well, especially where people may be uploading arbitrary sized files, is extremely difficult.  Having cracked this nut before, I would say start at the highest abstraction.  A user can upload a file and is returned a URL with the file's location.  So the user POSTs a file and gets back a response that's usually a 201/204 with the URL of the new file.  Even if you're using sockets, I would consider an HTTP based approach so you can roll the same service out to multiple types of clients and platforms.  However, you could probably write a very efficient implementation in sockets.

With either sockets or HTTP requests, the following will be the same on the server side.  On the server side you have an interface, such as FileLocator which takes a file id and a user.  The FileSystemFileLocator implements FileLocator and would locate the file on the filesystem. The tricky part is not putting more than about 1,000 or so directories or objects in a directory.  A common technique (if you assign each file a unique number), is to zero-pad and reverse the number so you have 12 numbers.  Each block of three digits becomes a directory name and the last 3 is the file name:  /123/400/000/000.pdf.  To get back the pretty file name, you track location, original filename and some meta-data in a database.

Then you can implement S3FileLocator, which uses S3 to store files.  MongoFileLocator to store the data in mongo, etc.  The challenge you will have is to figure out how to make sure that the metadata in the database (which you can access very quickly) is kept in sync with the reality on the filesystem or in S3.

When reading the file only read small chunks of the file (like 16k) and return those to the user in a loop until done.  If you read in the file all at once, you will use memory very inefficiently.  For example, on one project I was on a nitwit implemented this by reading the file from an SQL Server table into memory, and then, in memory, copying the object to write it back out to the client.  The database contained 50 megabyte power-point presentations.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create an account on dropbox which will give you a public folder. That folder can be used publicly or any user can access without any account or login password. So that folder become your server site or ftp and you do not need server code. Now public folder link become your server URL and port will be 80. Just implement client create separate folder for each user on dropbox public folder, which will help you to create different URL for each user. for their own data synching.